# How to set the gradient angle and type to the CAGradientLayer

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uicolor, cagradientlayer

Hi i am trying to get the color from the gradients where that color is set to another view .
I am able to set start and end color,but not able to set the angle and the type.

**Here are the values:
1.Startcolor:@"2b2b2b"
2.Endcolor:@"4a4a4a"
3.GradientAngle:90
4.GradientType:@"linear"**

```
UIView *theView=[[UIView alloc] init];
theView.frame=self.view.frame; 
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = theView.bounds;
UIColor *startColor = [self colorwithHexString:@"2b2b2b" alpha:1];
UIColor *endColor = [self colorwithHexString:@"4a4a4a" alpha:1];
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[startColor CGColor], (id)[endColor CGColor], nil];
[theView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 2):

CAGradientLayer has a `type` property (but the only supported value is axial):

> An axial gradient (also called a linear gradient) varies along an axis between two defined end points. All points that lie on a line perpendicular to the axis have the same color value.

The angle is determined by the `startPoint` and `endPoint` properties. Both are defined in the unit coordinate space of the layer's bounds (x and y range from 0 to 1).

Comment: Thanks for reply.can you please elaborate how to set the Angle property